# google URL shortener, wait for data to be fully received - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to use Google's URL shortener API.
I am using this code to shorten it using node JS:

```
function _shorten (url, callback) {
    if (!url) { 
        console.error('Please specify a valid url.');
        return; 
    }

    if (typeof _url.parse(url).protocol === 'undefined') {
        url = 'http://' + url;
    }

    if (!callback) { callback = false; }

    var key = _getKey(),
        options = {
            host: 'www.googleapis.com',
            port: 443,
            path: '/urlshortener/v1/url' + (key ? '?' + _querystring.stringify({'key': key}) : ''),
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        };

    var req = _https.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (d) {
            d = JSON.parse(d); // <--- here is the problem
            if (callback) {
                callback(d);
            } else {
                console.log(d.id || d.error);
            }
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) { console.error(e); });

    req.write(JSON.stringify({'longUrl': url}));

    req.end();
}
```

However, when I try to run it with a basic URL, I get the following error:

```
undefined:1
{
 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/PATH/node_modules/goo.gl/lib/googl.js:45:26)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnBody [as onBody] (http.js:142:22)
```

I believe this is because I am trying to parse the data I receive before I received it completely. When I remove  d = JSON.parse(d); my callback gets called several times and I get the following result:

```
{



"
k
i
n
d
"
:

"
u
r
l
s
hortener#url",
 "id": "http://goo.gl/test",
 "longUrl": "http://test.com"
}
```

How can I fix this? Should I do something like this as I am only interested in the 'id' field?:

```
    if d contains 'id' then 
     d = JSON.parse(d);
            if (callback) {
                callback(d);
            } else {
                console.log(d.id || d.error);
            }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I managed to fix it with this:

```
    var req = _https.request(options, function(res) {
        var message = "";
        var id = "id";
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (d) {
            message += d;

            var idIndex = message.indexOf(id);
            var didFindId = idIndex != -1;
               if (didFindId) {
                    if (callback) {
                        message = JSON.parse(message);
                        callback(message);   
                    } else {
                        console.log(d.id || d.error);
                    }
                }
        });
    });
```

I check if  my data contains "id" after accumulating all the data received so far and only then I send it

Answer (score 0):

You need to accumulate the data until it finishes and then do the `JSON.parse()`. So you keep augmenting the data within the `.on('data',...)` event handler and you need to transfer the `JSON.parse()` and the `callback` existence check in the `.on('end',...)` event handler.

From the Nodejs documentation on [http.ClientRequest](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest):

```
However, if you add a 'response' event handler, then you must consume the data from the
response object, either by calling response.read() whenever there is a 'readable' event,
or by adding a 'data' handler, or by calling the .resume() method. Until the data is
consumed, the 'end' event will not fire. Also, until the data is read it will consume
memory that can eventually lead to a 'process out of memory' error.
```

Comment: my problem is that the event 'end' never gets called :(

Comment: Can you try with the `close` event?